# Defining MySQL hostname config variable when using subdomains in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, subdomain

Let's say that we have a Codeigniter installation and the way to access that installation/website is subdomain.domain.com

In the database config of Codeigniter, what should the hostname variable be?
I tried the two below but I am still unable to connect to the database.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'subdomain.domain.com';
```

NOTE: I am sure that the username and password details are correct.

NOTE2: Does using subdomains counted as external source by MySQL? If yes, should I then turn on the option in MySQL to accept external request? Not sure if this is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
```

Try setting it to the ip address of the server.  That's how I always configure mine.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
```

on my local machine, it doesn't really have to be an IP address, only something that your machine can resolve to an IP address..